# if/else Mustache.php and Handlebars 2.0.0 compatibility

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache.php

My if else statements using the "^" for "false" or "not" used to work in both Handlebars 1.3.0 and Mustache.php. When I try the ^ for "if not" in Handlebars 2.0.0 it always disregards that block, no matter if true or false?

```js
{{#repo}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/repo}}
{{^repo}}
  No repos :({
{{/repo}}
```

Comment: I was wrong. The problem was caused by replacing compiling hbs files with grunt-handlebars-compiler to grunt-contrib-handlebars, and needing the processName option as explained here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564868/handlebars-precompile-type-error

Answer (score 0):

Well those are not simples `if/else` statements, those `^` inside the `{{}}` are called [inverted sections](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

> An inverted section begins with a caret (hat) and ends with a slash.
>   That is {{^person}} begins a "person" inverted section while
>   {{/person}} ends it.
>
> While sections can be used to render text one or more times based on
>   the value of the key, inverted sections may render text once based on
>   the inverse value of the key. That is, they will be rendered if the
>   key doesn't exist, is false, or is an empty list.

And there is not compatibility issues using `mustache` with `handlebars 2.0`, make sure the hash look like this.

```
{
  "repo": [] //or :false //or well it dosnt exists
}
```

Also you may wanna take a look into [this proposal to change some features of mustache](http://writing.jan.io/mustache-2.0.html)